# GUI representation of arrays in java

Tags: java, arrays, swing, user-interface, jlabel

I'm kinda new to java and I'm making an applet where I need to display an array (numbers from 0 to 255) like the ones in this applet (I am putting it inside a JScrollPane):

[RC4 Cipher Applet](http://www.usafa.edu/df/dfe/dfer/centers/accr/tools/RC4CipherApplet.html)

I also want to deal with each entry and the value inside it later.
I tried using JTable but the maximum number of columns is 100.
I thought about a JLabel for each entry but it would take forever..

Excuse me if this is a repeated question but I searched the questions here I couldn't find what I need

Oh and no this is not a homework I'm just working on a little project for myself :)
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried doing one column and each row being an index in a JTable instead?

Comment: thing is I want it to be horizontal not vertical, isn't there a way I can do like the one in the link?

Comment: Is there a specific benefit over horizontal vs vertical for what you are doing?  You may need to implement a custom swing panel to do horizontal displaying since most implemented panels tend to think 'vertically'

Comment: just for design purposes. I'll consider a vertical table if I run out of solutions. thank you :)

Comment: *"number of columns is 100. I thought about a JLabel for each entry but it would take forever.."*  No it wouldn't.  An app. can have thousands of labels and be responsive.  It pays to try these things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, using `JLabel`s  wouldn't take forever if you do something like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    contentPanel.add(new JLabel(array[i]));
}
```

That's the first approach. You could also draw a grid with the numbers yourself by subclassing JPanel and overriding `paintComponent(Graphics)`. Example:

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    int currX = 10, currY = 10; // A 10px offset
    int gridBoxSize = 50; // In pixels. Should be large enough for three digits.

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (currX + gridBoxSize > this.getWidth()) {
            currX = 10;
            currY += gridBoxSize;
        }
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.drawRect(currX, currY, gridBoxSize, gridBoxSize);
        g.drawString(new String(array[i]), currX + 2, currY + 2);
    }
}
```

Note:

- I assumed the array you are talking about in your question is declared like this: `int[] array;`;
- The above code is only a quick draft, I didn't compile or test it.

Comment: This is a solution, but without the added feature of editing the values (as I think they want to do)

Comment: the label-creating loop didn't come up to my mind! thanks lol.. as for the second approach I didn't really get it, I'll give it a try.

Comment: @justderb If that is needed you can store the JLabels in an array, instead of creating them on the fly and losing your reference to them.